# android modify meta data google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

all you guys who know things I don't :-)

I've run into this problem that may not be actually a problem, only a revelation that I don't know what I'm doing. AGAIN!

I'm uploading a JPEG with some description and indexable keywords. Works like a charm. But I can't figure out how to add/modify meta data later, without creating another instance of the file. So, when I add a picture of my dog with description "dog", I end up with what I wanted. But if I try to modify the metadata by either using:

```
      gooFl = drvSvc.files().insert(meta).execute();
```

or

```
      gooFl = drvSvc.files().insert(meta,null).execute();
```

I end up with a new file (of the same name) on GOOGLE Drive. 
See the code snippet below:

```
    File meta = new File();
    meta.setTitle("PicOfMyDog.jpg");
    meta.setMimeType("image/jpeg");
    meta.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(ymID)));
    File gooFl = null;
    if (bNewJPG == true) {
      meta.setDescription("dog");
      meta.setIndexableText(new IndexableText().setText("dog"));
      gooFl = drvSvc.files().insert(meta, 
       new FileContent("image/jpeg", new java.io.File(fullPath("PicOfMyDog.jpg"))))
       .execute();
    } else {
      meta.setDescription("dick");
      meta.setIndexableText(new IndexableText().setText("dick"));
      // gooFl = drvSvc.files().insert(meta).execute();
      gooFl = drvSvc.files().insert(meta,null).execute();
    }
    if (gooFl != null)
      Log.d("atn", "success  " + gooFl.getTitle());
```

It is the "else" branch I'm asking about. First file one has meatadata "dog", second "dick".
So, what's the solution. Do I delete the previous instance (and how)? Is there another syntax / method I don't know about?
thank you, sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to modify the metadata, use `files.patch`.

```
drvSvc.files().patch(id, meta).execute();
```

In cases you need both modify the metadata and the file contents, use `files.update`.

```
drvSvc.files().update(id, meta, content).execute();
```

Insertions make POST requests that always create a new resource.

Comment: THANK YOU, it's the second time you saved my life. Like having a guardian angel pulling me from swamps my ignorance leads me to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Files.Patch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch#examples) if you want to update only Metadata. `files().insert` always creates a new file.

A full list of `File` commands and what operations you need to use can be found in the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/#Files)